# jQuery Mobile loading spinner not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I seem to be having a problem with the jQuery Mobile spinner.
It seems to work OK when I'm using my desktop browser, chrome but doesn't work on my mobile browser on Android ICS

Code I'm using below

```
$(document).live('pageinit', (function() {
    $(document).ajaxStart($.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg());
    $(document).ajaxStop($.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg());
}));
```

Comment: You may want to provide more code or context to get some better answers.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your ajax start/stop happens so quickly that you don't see it.  Check out the answers on this post to see if they help: [jQuery modal dialog on ajaxStart event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953559/jquery-modal-dialog-on-ajaxstart-event)

Answer (score 0):

The following might probably work page Id as 'main'

```
$(document).delegate('div[data-role=page][id=main]', 'pageshow', function() {
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
});
```

Thanks,
Prodeveloper